# UINavCtrlr push animation shifts content partway off then dissapears

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I've encountered a problem with the UINavigationController default transition where the transition is abrupt and incomplete. A picture is worth 1000 words, so below is what the transition looks like:

The root view controller:

[image: Root Controller]

The root slides to the left about 1/4 of the width, while the pushed view controller appears on top (notice the "title" text overlayed in the top left).

[image: Mid-animation]

The animation stops and the root controller suddenly disappears to show the pushed view controller.

[image: pushed controller]

The major problem is that the root controller doesn't just slide off like it normally does. It slides about 1/4 of the way, stops with the pushed controller's contents over it, then suddenly disappears.

This is my code in the root controller to transition to the new viewcontroller:
`[self.navigationController pushViewController:editAttributeViewController animated:TRUE];`

The only complicating factor I can think of is that this occurs (as you can probably tell) in a modal view controller (UIModalPresentationFormSheet).

Any ideas as to why the animation is not functioning properly?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be wrong, and forgive me if i am, but I think this is a visual defect that happens when you don't have a background color set for the new View Controller.  The new view controller is transparent so it APPEARS that the animation isn't as smooth as it should be.  Try setting a background color for the view controller that you are trying to present and see if that helps.

Comment: wow... seriously? That was exactly my problem! I can't believe I did that... Thanks a lot! Will accept your answer once the time allotment allows. :)

Comment: No problem at all!  I've ran into that problem a few times..very annoying indeed!  Glad i can help!